# Calculate Active Customers 30 days ago in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like to calculate user churn in my rails app.

*eg. Take all the customers you lose in the last 30 days, and divide it by the total number of active customers you had 30 days ago. You do not include any new sales from that month.*

I have a `:deleted_at` column on my user table which determines when someone cancels, so the number of customers lost in the last month is relatively easy.

The calculation I don't know where to start with is **'Active Customers 30 days ago'**

Comment: That depends on your database and your definition of *active*. *Active* might mean a *user who signed in at least once* (do you store datetime of last login?) Or an active user is an user who brought something (then have a look at when sales where created).

Comment: @spickermann Sorry if it wasn't clear but I meant that everyone is who is not deleted is active in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'Active Customers 30 days ago' should be something like that :

```
previous_day = Date.today - 30.days
User.where("created_at < :date AND (deleted_at > :date OR deleted_at is NULL)", {date: previous_day})
```

Edit : You could see it like this

-Result : Take all the customers you lose in the last 30 days, and divide it by the total number of active customers you had 30 days ago. You do not include any new sales from that month.

```
( (User.active_now - User.active_and_created_in_the_last_x_days) - User.was_active_x_days_ago ) / User.was_active_x_days_ago
```

-Take all the customers you lose in the last 30 days:

```
(User.active_now - User.active_and_created_in_the_last_x_days) - User.was_active_x_days_ago )
```

-Total number of active customers you had 30 days ago:

```
User.was_active_x_days_ago
```

-You do not include any new sales from that month.

```
User.active_and_created_in_the_last_x_days
```

Comment: The request take all accounts created before d-30 (including you who signed up few years ago). For the "Active Customers 30 days ago", it doesn't matter what happens between d-30 and d-day.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting an error using your code at `deleted_at = nil`
Solved it by changing to `deleted_at is NULL`